# Joining Objects in MySQL - JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, object, serialization

I used JOIN to join tables together and retrieve information. After retrieving objects I am adding that information to a table.

my query:

```
"SELECT L.LibPassport AS LibPassport,L.Object as LObject,G.Passport AS GPassport,"
                    + "G.Object AS GObject,O.* FROM Orders AS O, Guest AS G, Librarian AS L WHERE O.Passport = G.Passport";
```

Firstly it gives me an error as `Columns LObject not found` then I changed all to only as `Object` , query worked smoothy but then its not adding all objects to List.

Method for sql is below:

```
public List<Object> getReport() {
    List<Object> obj = new ArrayList<Object>();
    Object x = null;
    String query = "SELECT L.LibPassport AS LibPassport,L.Object as Object,G.Passport AS GPassport,"
                    + "G.Object AS Object,O.*,O.Object AS Object FROM Orders AS O, Guest AS G, Librarian AS L WHERE O.Passport = G.Passport";
    try {
        state = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = state.executeQuery();
        //Librarian
        while(rs.next()) {
            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(rs.getBytes("Object"));
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
            x = ois.readObject();
            obj.add(x);
            ois.close();
            bais.close();
        }

    }catch(SQLException | IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

and then I am accessing and differentiating using `instanceof` e.g.

```
 if(obj.get(i) instanceof Transaction) {
                a = (Transaction) obj.get(i);
                fill.add(4,a.getBorrowDate());
                fill.add(5,a.getReturnDate());

            }
```

But its not getting all the objects, it either doesn't access or only 1 object. however the same query in mysql shows me all objects.

If you want further details please let me know.

Comment: The sql does not actually contain the join keyword or a join to the Librarian tables.  The result set should be a cross product of all rows in the O and P tables x all rows in the librarian table.

Comment: Yes, the query results in all objects/columns/rows when executed n mysql. but while I am executing it in eclipse it will just get two objects lets say only of Order thats it.